# Problema DNS en cloudflare

Tags: hosting, dns, dominio

Hola y gracias por la ayuda. Tengo una web en Cloudflare Pages con un dominio de nic.ar (Argentina)
Cuando le pongo al dominio www me da "Connection timed out Error code 522"
Cuando le di alta agregó automáticamente dos registros CNAME: el 1° con el nombre de mi dominio y el 2° con www
Cuál puede ser el problema?
gracias y saludos para todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución en el foro de Cloudflare (está en inglés) hay que agregar el dominio con www también en "dominios personalizados"

Answer (score 0):

Revisaste si en la parte de dominios personalizados esta configurado y esta en verde activo?

También prueba si tienes acceso con la url que genera pages internamente *.pages.dev para descartar problemas con la web.

Comment: Hola... Sí, aparece activo. Y funciona perfecto con .pages.dev y con mi dominio. El problema es sólo con www

Comment: Hola, En dominio personalizados aparecen los dos registros? Un registro con www y otro con el dominio solo?

Comment: Acabo de probar a forzar un registro en el dns sin estar dado de alta en pages y me da el error 522.

Comment: sí, los dos tipo CNAME. Me los generó Cloudflare al dar alta el dominio

Comment: Elimina el registro DNS de www y elimina el dominio personalizado www en pages y añadelo de nuevo. El problema esta en pages que no esta identificando el registro www. A ver si con eso funciona

Comment: probé las dos cosas y tampoco funciona

Comment: Encontré la solución en el foro de Cloudflare (está en inglés) hay que agregar el dominio con www también en "dominios personalizados" gracias PLP igual por el interés

Comment: Debieras añadir tu solución en respuesta a tu propia pregunta, por si alguien nos visita buscando solución al mismo problema